# GLOBAL variable in PHP class

Tags: php, class, variables, global

I would like to use a simple variable that makes a role in the class... however, this is not working.

```
$GLOBALS['world'] = "Isara";

class Character{
    var $name;
    var $status;
    static $content;
    function __construct($name){
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->getCharInfo();
    }

    private function getCharInfo(){
        if(empty(self::$content)){
            self::$content = file_get_contents("http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=$GLOBALS['world']",0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$GLOBALS[...]` to access global variables is correct. However, when embedding array accessors in strings, you need to wrap the variable in brackets.

So, instead of

```
file_get_contents("... $GLOBALS['world']");
```

you could use one of the following:

```
file_get_contents("... {$GLOBALS['world']}");
file_get_contents("... " . $GLOBALS['world']);
```

or:

```
global $world;
file_get_contents("... $world");
```